# Chinese symbols in my google search for my website

Tags: html

My site got recently hacked. I have fixed everything but for one thing.
When you search on google growfeeder you find my website www.growfeeder.com.
But it is showing alot of wierd symbols on my google search.

Does somebody know how to fix it?

This is what it looks like:

[image: Google Search screenshot]

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: To speed up things, go to google webmasters console and force google to fetch and index that page again, otherwise just wait a couple of days.

Comment: If you have fixed everything then you can wait for some days and it will all be fine. In my case even after fixing everything it was still saying that my site could be harmful. If it still shows the same for you, you can report google that your website is now fixed and not harmful any more. That's how I fixed my site.

Answer (score 1):

Check the meta tags in the head.

```
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="something here.">
</head>
```

Chances are google hasn't re-indexed your site.